# How To Draw A Line Dividing The Cell's Accessory View

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview, accessoryview

I just wanted to know how I could draw a line dividing the cell's accessory view from the rest of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a thin UIView (or UIImageView if you wanted a fancier divider) like so.

```
UIView *divider = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 3, 1, 38)];
[divider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:divider];
[divider release];
```

If you're using one of UITableView's default accessory views, your content view will be squashed to make room for the accessory, so you your x-coordinate may have to change to sit at the very edge of the content view.